# Set proxy data for an app

Tags: .net, proxy, httpwebrequest

I have a few .NET apps which use the HttpWebRequest. My gut says i can create a config or manifest file and set the proxy data in there and .NET will automatically load it. But i dont know if that exist and if my gut is wrong.

Is there a way to set the proxy data for my apps? Can i do the same for my one app that uses the ie browser control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use a **different** proxy? Or the system's proxy? Note that `WebBrowser` will probably work differently since this is activex, but IIRC `HttpWebRequest` will use the  winhttp proxy by default. So all you need to do is configure winhttp!

How to do this varies per OS; typically it is easiest to simply import the wininet settings from IE:

Vista/Win7:

```
netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie
```

XP (from memory, please double-check):

```
proxycfg -u
```

You can also set the proxy per-application (rather than system-wide) via the config file; [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6484zdc1.aspx).

Comment: how do i write a per app proxy when it isnt asp? After googling i can only find web.config

Comment: That would be app.config (which becomes MyApplication.exe.config)

Comment: Thanks :D (make this 15 letters)